# MARS - Address out of range

Tags: memory, out-of-memory, mips, primes, mars-simulator

I am writing a program in Mars MIPS Simulator that finds all the prime numbers up to 65,025 and then creates a pixel by pixel representation of them on a 256x256 bitmap display, in the form of the [Ulam Spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulam_spiral).

My program's `data` segment looks like this:

```
display:    .word   0:65536         # allocates a memory address for each  pixel, and initialises each to 0 (256 x 256)
numPixels:  .word   655536          # number of pixels on 256x256 display
black:      .word   0x00000000      # hex code for black
white:      .word   0x00FFFFFF      # hex code for white

primeArray: .word   1:65025         # array of 65025 elements initialised to '1' (1 = prime, 0 = not prime)
length:     .word   65025           # length of primeArray
```

What I am trying to do in this `data` segment is to reserve:

- 65,536 words to correspond to each pixel
- 3 words to store '65,536' and the hex codes for black and white
- 65,025 words for integers 1 - 65,025
- 1 word to store the number '65,025'

in that given order.

The program works by using the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) to iterate through `primeArray` and stores the prime numbers as `1`, non-primes as `0`. So far, I have two functions that work fine independently:

- The first that clears the bitmap display by iterating through each of the 65,536 pixels and setting each of their colours to white.
- The second iterates through `primeArray` and stores the number of the corresponding index to `0` or `1` if it is prime or not by using the algorithm of the Sieve of Eratosthenes.

If I run each of these functions on their own, the program executes with no errors. However, if I try to execute `clearDisplay` followed by `calcPrimes`, I get the following memory error:

```
line 63: Runtime exception at 0x0040009c: address out of range 0x10400000
```

where line 63 is inside a loop that sets `primeArray[i] = 0` if that element is not prime.

What is causing this error? Is the data segment large enough to store all that I am hoping to before execution?

The assignment instructions ask to include a subroutine that `clears a block of memory` - is this relevant to my issue?

Comment: Post the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a typo in your data segment:

```
numPixels:  .word   655536
```

256*256 is 65536, not 655536.